# nvl , Where, IN clauses

Tags: sql, oracle

Is this correct?

```
select * from t1
where nvl(t1.a,t1.b) in (select id from t2 where name = 'Apple')
```

a,b are the columns in t1 for the Id from t2.

I want all the rows that have id for 'Apple' either in t1.a or t1.b

if a is null, id will be in b.

if b is null, id will be in a.

Comment: Your code looks like it does what you want.  I prefer `coalesce()`, the ANSI standard function.

Comment: I dont seem to get the results I am expecting with this logic.

Comment: Is it certain that at least one of both a and b is null?

Comment: Only one of them will have the id, however the one without the valid id may have -9999. would this be a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want all the rows that have id for 'Apple' either in t1.a or t1.b

No, it is not correct.

Your query will get the rows where `t1.a` is an `id` in `t2` or where `t1.a` is `null` and `t1.b` is an `id` in `t2`.

You want:

```
select *
from   t1
where  EXISTS ( select 1
                from   t2
                where  name = 'Apple'
                and    ( t1.a = t2.id OR t1.b = t2.id ) )
```

or:

```
SELECT *
FROM   t1
WHERE  a IN ( SELECT id FROM t2 WHERE name = 'Apple' )
OR     b IN ( SELECT id FROM t2 WHERE name = 'Apple' )
```

or (if you need to enforce the `NULL` in the non-matching value):

```
select *
from   t1
where  EXISTS ( select 1
                from   t2
                where  name = 'Apple'
                and    (  ( t1.a = t2.id AND t1.b IS NULL )
                       OR ( t1.b = t2.id AND t1.a IS NULL ) ) )
```

Comment: how should this be written? Can it be written only with an OR?

Comment: @Skn Updated with an alternative with an `OR`

Comment: @MT0 . . . Although I do prefer `exists` to the original logic, it is equivalent.  You have misquoted the OP by leaving out "if a is null, id will be in b; if b is null, id will be in a."  This is the same as your logic.  The problem would appear to be described in a comment (no doubt written after you answered).  `a` can also contain -9999.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Its unclear whether `-9999` is being used instead of `NULL` or is a value that should exclude the row... if its the latter then this works if its the former then change `( t1.a = t2.id AND t1.b IS NULL )` in the last query to `( t1.a = t2.id AND ( t1.b IS NULL OR t1.b = -9999 ) )` (and similar for the next line).

Answer (score 1):

It's correct, but inefficient.
I would write

```
select * from t1
where t1.a in (select id from t2 where name = 'Apple')
union 
select * from t1
where t1.b in (select id from t2 where name = 'Apple')
```

Comment: Wrong. Union discards duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

If the values for *a* and *b* in one record are -9999 and the id of apple, your query will not return the record, because *a* is not null, and so -9999 is compared with the apple ID, not the value of *b*

I suggest this, assuming that you have only one record in *t2* that represents the *"Apple"*:

```
select *
from   t1
where (select id from t2 where name = 'Apple') in (a, b)
```

If you could have multiple records in *t2* with the name *"Apple"* then I would suggest this:

```
select     distinct t1.*
from       t1
inner join t2 
        on t2.name = 'Apple'
       and t2.id in (t1.a, t1.b)
```

Comment: If `name` is not a unique column then you will get `ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row`.

Comment: Yes, it was an assumption I made. I have mentioned it in my answer now, and provided an alternative for when multiple apple records could exist.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is described in the comment -- the logic in the question is not correct, because a value could be -9999.  You can do what you want as:

```
select *
from t1
where (case when t1.a is null or t1.a = -9999 then t1.b else t1.a end) in 
         (select id from t2 where name = 'Apple');
```